# Translating Javascript Function to Python

Tags: javascript, python, angular, encryption, obfuscation

I am far from knowing javascript however am attempting to solve a decode function and translate it to python. Within the sites code it generates a string of length 100 characters which gets plugged into a function called decode as shown here and returns a string of 96 characters in length. I've already started trying to translate this into a usable python function.

```js
decode.call(undefined, "TaYWuqsVvO1zjYWnzcZaSyOucBGnvoz7Jiq2RLZBvTk35uaNHlYrwFb8V2fqQqBjVOGPyuu4WD1dMXeX1Si1GqVIWJYXey75PQMS");

function decode(message) {
  /** @type {number} */
  var offset = 71 + 28 * 75 + 14 + 38;
  if (this.angular.isDate(offset)) {
    console.log("Offset derived as: {", offset, "}");
  }
  return _.replace(message, /./g, function(char, increment) {
    return String.fromCharCode((char.charCodeAt(0) * increment + offset) % 77 + 48);
  });
}
;
```

Javascript is not my native language so any help and explaining of the different function calls would help a lot. I understand already that in this case our offset is an integer value of 2223. And then we take our message and replace its content. However I am a bit confused by the increment function and the `/./g` portion.

Comment: Look at `re.sub` with a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear in your code what `this.angular` is all about, but it seems like you are most interested in the string substitution. In python you can do something like:

```
def decode(s):
    offset = 71 + 28 * 75 + 14 + 38;
    return "".join(chr((ord(a) * increment + offset)  % 77 + 48) for increment, a in enumerate(s) )

p = decode("TaYWuqsVvO1zjYWnzcZaSyOucBGnvoz7Jiq2RLZBvTk35uaNHlYrwFb8V2fqQqBjVOGPyuu4WD1dMXeX1Si1GqVIWJYXey75PQMS")
```

This makes `p` equal to:

```
's:>Dy@pe:8BGNueGAhvnQsRohGqRldO1`sk^@NFG=^BK<CoUj^cMB4^sPtfS|N1^K[hUhgBoAJzEss><l>eeI_wKGOusZ11D_vs]'
```

which is the same value I get in javascript.

`chr()` and `ord()` are roughly the same as `String.fromCharCode()` and `char.charCodeAt()`. You can get both the `increment` and value using `enumerate`. After that the rest is just math.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the translation between languages.<3  Solved!